# segmentation fault when using argv[1]

Tags: c++, argv

when i try to run this program with : ./prog_name eventCNT i confront with segmentation fault error while with other argument everything is ok...

```c
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("Application for up/down/random counter on 7 seg display\n");

    if ( (strcmp(argv[1], "eventCNT") == 0 &&  argc != 2) || (strcmp(argv[1], "eventCNT") != 0 &&  argc != 3) )

    {

        printf( "usage: %s <direction or event counting> <delay>\n", argv[0] );
        printf( "valid direction : up, down, updown, random\n");
        printf( "valid event counting : eventCNT\n");
        printf ("recommended delay range in ms : 0 to 1000\n");
    }
    else
    {
        .
       .
       .  

    }
}
```

Comment: couldn't reproduce. when I run this with a single command line argument it works fine

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: In addition to the problems with checking `argc` and accessing `argv` already mentioned, it seems that the code you've left out (the `else` clause) is what's causing the segfault because that's what executing when you run `./prog_name eventCNT`.

Comment: This kind of a problem should nearly always have a [mcve]. That way you don't accidentally leave out relevant code and waste the time of other people.

Answer (score 2):

You should check `argc` before accessing `argv`

If `argc == 1` and you are accessing `argv[1]` first, you are accessing invalid memory because `argv` only has one member, which is `argv[0]`

C++ evaluates statements from left to right, therefore having undefined behaviour first and then checking whether it was ok to do this is not the best way. Invert the checks to `argc` and `argv`

Actually you should write code in a more defensive way like

```
if (argc < 2)
{
   // Error, not enough arguments
   return -1
}

// From here you know that argv[1] will be a valid string to something and you can freely get `argv[1]`
```

Comment: but i ran this program with 2 arguments (./prog_name eventCNT) and receive this error

Comment: If this does not solve your issue please follow this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
if (argc >= 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "eventCNT") == 0)
```

not

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "eventCNT") == 0 && argc != 2)
```

Because if arguments are less than 2, `argv[1]` is not defined, will point to a random memory address. Therefore a segmentation fault occurs.

Also `strcmp` has undefined behavior if you points to something not a null-terminated string. see [strcmp here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Comment: Actually `argv[argc]` is NULL, not undefined.

Comment: but i ran this program with 2 arguments (./prog_name eventCNT) and receive this error